# botot3 attach_volume throwing volume not available

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to attach volume to instance using boto3 but its failed to attach with below error

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IncorrectState) when calling the AttachVolume operation: vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is not 'available'.

I can see volumme exists in aws console but somehow boto3 is not able to attach volume.

```py
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "us-west-1"

client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                          region_name='us-west-1')

response1 = client.attach_volume(
        VolumeId=volume_id,
        InstanceId=instance_id,
        Device='/dev/sdg',

    )
```

I tried using aws cli for attaching the same and its working fine after exporting AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-1"

Also tried exporting the same in python script using os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "us-west-1" but python script is failing with the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: How are you creating the volume? Can you run `client.describe_volume_status(volume_id)` as given over [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_volume_attribute) and post the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I am not giving enough time after creating ebs volume. I am able to attach now after adding sleep